# Lead-acid battery screening options

Tags: batteries, testing, lead-acid

We have a situation where we have on-hand many tens of thousands of 12 V lead-acid AGM batteries. The vendor had production issues, and we've found around 5-10% of these have an unacceptably low capacity (like around 20% of the Ah they're supposed to have). Most are OK, some are excellent.

We have determined the reason is that the AGM material is either not being compressed enough or compressed too much in the bad ones. The vendor wasn't adequately controlling plate thicknesses. So when we get a unit with middle-of-the-road plates, it's fine. If there's one extraordinarily thin or thick plate, that's when there are problems. I'm not a chemist, but it does seem this is "the cause". In a pulse-test, there's plenty electrolyte at the plates to deliver the brief current pulse, but since ion flow is impeded by incorrect AGM contact pressure, a longer term load exhausts the material in direct contact with the plates and we see bad Ah as a result.

I can't crucify the vendor for internal political reasons, so making them eat the batteries isn't an option. (No, it's not my fault either ;)

My problem is that I need to try to find a method to identify these bad ones before they're packed and shipped to customers.  Unfortunately we have found "for sure" we can't use a common pulse test. I purchased about a dozen different models and we have a custom one we use on our lines; none of these are able to pick out the bad ones. These batteries, good or bad, don't show any variance in their open-circuit voltage measurements, so that's not a suitable path either.

I've only found two methods to identify them:

1. Do a full load charge/discharge test. I run this 4 or 5 times, and the bad ones usually are easily found this way. Obviously though, that's impractical to actually implement.
2. Send them to customers and see who complains.

Needless to say, option #2 isn't an acceptable method either. So I'm stuck with "no option" at present.

What I'm going to do is perform a load test on a couple hundred pieces, but not a brief pulse. Instead I'm planning on drawing about 20 A for a couple of minutes and record the voltage curve.  I'll also take impedance readings (standard 1 kHz test). Batteries will be top-charged prior to making the test.

The hope is that this longer duration load test will show some more significant voltage drop on "bad" units than on good ones.  After taking that data, I'll do the 4-5 full cycle test to positively identify good & bad. If the gods of statistics are on my side, I'll be able to identify bad ones with this heavy load test (or by simple impedance measurement). We can tolerate this 1 or 2 minute test on the line, I just can't accept a 3-day test.

So my question to the community:

Are there any OTHER lead-acid characteristics I could potentially measure and make a judgement with? I can only think of load and impedance.  I can't open the batteries (they're glued shut), so all I can do is probe the 2 connection points.

Fingers crossed somebody out there is more knowledgeable or more clever than me!

Comment: When I went to school (about ten years ago), one of my professors was researching using AC impedance measurements to determine battery quality (of lithium cells, but there may be research on using it for lead-acid too). Maybe that might be worth looking into?

Comment: @Hearth Thx for the thought!   Yeah, I'm already planning on that.  The standard industry test is 1kHz AC.   I preliminarily tested a few and it doesn't seem to be panning out, but I'll withhold judgement until I test all 200+ pieces.

Comment: Plate thickness might be measurable as mass difference, assuming the vendor tightly enough controlled fill volume. Also, now really guessing into the blue: plate thickness possibly has mechanical consequences. Ground one contact, measure the voltage on the other while drawing (or supplying) a constant (discharge or charge) current, while shaking the battery on a well-defined stand. Could be that voltage correlates highly with acceleration. Maybe even a vibration analysis (press speaker onto one side, mic onto other) might correlate nicely with brokenness.

Comment: @KyleB It seems to me that the manufacturer should be: (1) establishing criteria that they consider an "acceptable" percentage of bad batteries during production, and (2) monitoring their production lines and identifying those producing an unacceptable level, and (3) figuring out an assignable cause, and (4) determining and implementing corrective actions. The last pair are lumped into what's called an ACCA -- assignable cause/corrective action. It's a well understood process in quality control. Why aren't they pushing hard on these details and instead leaving it up to you to reject some?

Comment: Can you just charge them all to maximum, and then put a 1C load on them? After one half hour the bad ones will be fully depleted while the good ones should have at least 20-50% SOC.

Comment: @jonk  Can't argue with any of that.   Someday you and I can maybe sit down over a beer and I can describe why none of that is feasible.  I can't say it on an open forum however....   I'll just leave it at that

Comment: @PStechPaul  That's a pretty good idea.  Hadn't really considered how long it would take to genuinely drain one.  I'm gonna put this in the "think about it" category.   The downside is the time & manual effort required.  This would require a half-hour or thereabouts connected to a measuring device to discharge, then they would need a charging session again afterwards.   I won't be able to cycle batteries through fast enough (not enough resources...)  I wish I were kidding about the "multiple 10's of thousands" we have to look at....

Comment: @MarcusMüller Interesting idea.  I might probe that a bit.  Definitely had not considered attempting a MECHANICAL test!    Thx for the idea  :)

Comment: It would not really require a measuring device. Just the appropriate size resistor, and perhaps a timer to remove it after the time is up. Then the good batteries should still read a reasonable voltage, maybe 11 volts, while those that are depleted would be 9 volts or less. and can be discarded (recycled). An incandescent lamp might work well, as it will draw more current as the voltage decreases, so when the light goes out the battery is depleted.

Comment: Sounds like a good use for xrays. Just turn up at your local airport and line up your batteries on the conveyer to the xray machine!  Hopefully the differences are easily visible. Otherwise an impedance test might yield quick answers. Hopefully the cost of detecting the bad ones is much cheaper than the batteries themselves.

Comment: While 100% testing is obviously best, are there any lot markings or other distinctions that could be used to possibly identify most of the questionable ones? This kind of situation is literally why they are almost always present.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's a process issue, so every lot unfortunately has about the same % failures

Comment: @Kartman Thx for sharing your thoughts!    At first we suspected broken plates and some preliminary investigation showed a few.  That could possibly be seen on an X-ray.   The real culprit however proved to be the thickness of the plates.   They vary by about 0.020" .... They need to be more like 0.005" accurate.   I don't think we'll pick THAT up on an X-ray.   The vendor was casting them, they're changing that process along with some others.  But doesn't unfortunately get me out of the current situation

Comment: You might be able to detect a difference in the charging phase if you monitor the temperature at the connection post. If the battery capacity is low then the incoiming energy will, I think, be converted to heat. That may also indirectly cause a difference in the voltage due to temperature as well as SOC . The latter would have a different time constant and may be detectable.

Comment: Depending on cost of batteries and ease of replacement. perhaps send an extra battery to each customer as a spare, but with the caution that one of them might exhibit low capacity. But I think a quick load test on fully charged batteries should weed out at least some of the worst ones.